# Checkboxes and Radio buttons don't show on printout, but do on pdf

Tags: pdf, webforms, printing-web-page

As the title says really.

I have a web page with various checkbox and radio button options that help create a quote. This needs to be then printed out.

This all works fine if I print to PDF - the page is shown exactly the same. However, if I print to an actual printer, checkboxes and radio buttons aren't shown.

I've worked around this by running a function when a checkbox/radio button is clicked, that outlines the div around the button in black, so its not really a problem now.

But why does this happen?

Comment: So when you print the HTML from a browser to paper, stuff vanishes, but the PDF is fine?  CSS can hide things when printing, as could script.

Comment: I am using a print stylesheet to hide some things, but radio/checkboxes aren't affected. To create the pdf I still do the usual print command - its odd that printing to two printer devices (pdf creator = virtual printer, and a real printer) produces different results.